# Add multiple replacement labels for a source_label

Tags: prometheus

I want to transform the following metric

```
time__2xx_count{instance="localhost:9991",job="finagle_exporter",original_key="time/2XX.count"}
```

to

```
time__2xx_count{instance="localhost:9991",job="finagle_exporter",status="2XX",type="count"}
```

I would like to extract the status and metric type from the original_key source_label. I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [original_key]
    regex: 'time\/(.*)\.(.*)'
    replacement: '$1'
    target_label: status

  - source_labels: [original_key]
    regex: 'time\/(.*)\.(.*)'
    replacement: '$2'
    target_label: type
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [original_key]
    regex: 'time/(.+)\..+'
    replacement: '$1'
    target_label: status

  - source_labels: [original_key]
    regex: 'time/.+\.(.+)'
    replacement: '$1'
    target_label: type
```

Comment: That didn't work either. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: I think you need to use "metric_relabel_configs". I updated the answer.